# Batch File Rename Using Mapping File

Tags: scripting, rename

I have a large collection of image files, for example:

```
a.png, b.png, c.png, etc
```

If I have a file with mappings of filenames to numbers, like so (ignore the format, it could be anything):

```
a=>1
b=>2
c=>3
...
```

Is there any easy way to batch rename all the files using the mapping file to:

```
1.png, 2.png, 3.png, etc
```

I'm looking for unix/linux commands. I know I can write a very simple script, but just curious if there is any other technique.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a single command for *everything*; that's the point of having a scriptable shell.

```
while read -r old new; do
    mv "$old.png" "$new.png"
done < map.txt
```

Comment: But I want one command.  Something like, 
"renamefilesfrommappingfile <mappingfile> ."  :)

Comment: @steve: `renamefilesfrommappingfile() { local old new; while read -r old new; do mv "$old" "$new"; done < "$1"; }`

Comment: Haha. Good one.

Comment: You could make this a bit more general by playing with $IFS before and after the while loop;

Comment: Missing colon (;) after "$new.png". Too little for SE to accept the correction.

Comment: Only if you try to put everything in a single line. Otherwise (as in the current 3-line example code), line breaks will work everywhere a semicolon would be required and you don't need to use both.

Comment: what is the format of the map.txt file in this example?

Answer (score 2):

Without sed, you may do replacements like this in bash:

```
for line in  $(< patterns) ; do  echo "Pattern: " $line " char: "  ${line/=>*/} " nr: " ${line/*=>/}; done
```

('patterns' would be the file with a=>1 and so on) which leads to:

```
for line in  $(< patterns) ; do
  c=${line/=>*/}
  n=${line/*=>/}
  mv $c.png $n.png 
done
```

The manpage of bash lists this and other, interesting options under 'string substitution'.

Maybe perls `rename` is an interesting option too. It allows mass renamings with patterns, like

```
rename 's/^a/1/' a*png
```

On ubuntu, it comes with the perl-package, afaik.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way with perl:

```
cat mapfile | perl -e 'my$h={eval join(",",<>)};while (($k,$v)=each%$h){`mv $k.png $v.png`}'
```

---

Second try:

```
perl -nle '(@a=map{s/^\s+//;s/\s+$//;s/'/\\'/g;$_}split/\s*=>\s*/,$_,2)and`mv \'$a[0].png\' \'$a[1].png\'`'
```

Works with:

```
Someone's $tupid file name    =>   renamed by "simple" script?!
```

Comment: -1 for `eval`'ing the input, for eval'ing *barewords* on the right side of `=>`, and for using `\`mv\`` instead of whitespace-safe [rename()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html).

Comment: Why not something like: `perl -nle 'my ($old, $new) =  split /=>/; rename "$old.png", "$new.png"' mapfile`. Another advantage of avoiding eval is that you can actually change the pattern as the question indicates may be necessary.

Comment: @grawity: `perldoc rename`: Behavior of this function varies *wildly* depending on your system implementation. For example, it will usually not work across *file system boundaries*, even though the *system mv* command sometimes compensates for this. Other restrictions include whether it works on directories, open files, or pre-existing files. Check perlport and either the rename(2) manpage or equivalent system documentation for details.[italics mine]

Comment: @Axeman: thanks for the heads up on rename! But the eval is still ugly.

Comment: @Axeman: Use `File::Copy` to copy or move files on all but antique versions of Perl.

Comment: @Axeman: Renaming within the same directory, as in the question, generally does not cross fs boundaries.

Comment: @grawity, I was thinking the same thing shortly after I posted it, but oh well--he doesn't say anything about complicated file names either--he doesn't say anything about wily hackers intercepting your rename one-liner to make you eval bad code, either--so are we talking about the *general* case, or the *specific*.

Comment: Not necessarily wily "hackers". The 1st-attempt `eval` would break if the new name was a Perl function name too, which aren't that uncommon.

Comment: @Axeman: Also, *still* -1 for the regexitis instead of `system("mv", $old, $new)`. Sorry :D

Comment: @grawity, no problem. It was a slap-dash deal anyway.